# AngularJS routing doesn't work with templateUrl?

Tags: angularjs

I tried so hard to get this work but all my tries failed. I'm trying to learn Angular routing, I started very simple: created 4 files in the same folder: index.html, page1.html, page2.html and page3.html. 
this is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>routing</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<script src="D:\Developer Library\MyAngular\angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="D:\Developer Library\MyAngular\Scripts\angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <a href="#page1">one</a>
    <a href="#page2">two</a>
    <a href="#page3">three</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script>
                var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
                app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider
                        .when('/page1', { templateUrl: 'D:\Developer Library\dom\AngularRouting\page1.html' }).
                        when('/page2', { template: '<h1>page2.html</h1>' })//the template is working fine unlike templateUrl
                        .when('/page3', { template: '<h1>page3.html</h1>' });
                    //page1.html, page2.html, page3.html are just files holding headers with some text.-->
                })
            </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I got these errors in the console window:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///D:/Developer%20LibrarydomAngularRoutingpage1.html. Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
>   chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

and:

> Error: [$compile:tpload]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$compile/tpload?p0=D%3ADeveloper%20LibrarydomAngularRoutingpage1.html&p1=-1&p2=
>       at angular.min.js:6
>       at angular.min.js:156
>       at angular.min.js:131
>       at m.$eval (angular.min.js:145)
>       at m.$digest (angular.min.js:142)
>       at m.$apply (angular.min.js:146)
>       at HTMLBodyElement. (angular.min.js:115)
>       at Sf (angular.min.js:37)
>       at HTMLBodyElement.d (angular.min.js:37)

I made every possible change to get it work: I changed the `href` value of the anchor elements to `/#/page1`, `#/page1`, `/page`, `page` , I also changed the `templateUrl` value to similar values (my last try was the full path of the file!)
I'm actually confused between the `href` value and the first parameter of `when` method and the `templateUrl`, so I have some questions that I think will help me understand how routing work in angular:

What each of them refers to: are the `href` and the first argument of `when` method the same?
Can I assign the `href` attribute any value, and refer to it in the `when` argument?

Is `templareUrl` value related to the location of the current file(index.html),

What does the hash symbol # mean and why it's important?

Comment: do provide a path where you have hosted your application instead of `D:\...` may be it could be `\Scripts\angular-route.js` & `\Scripts\angular.min.js`

Answer (score 1):

Angular is loading templates via AJAX, and AJAX can not access local file system.

You must run you app on a server (you can use local server) for templateUrl to work.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain the convention between the hash symbol in the anchor and the forward slash in the config function, or give a link explaining it if possible?

Comment: The hash symbol is how angular detects changes in the URL without reloading the page (the hash is originaly used for in-page bookmarks), so angular take advantage of this mechanisim to detect changes in the URL that does not cause page reload but will trigger angular routing. Angular also support HTML5 mode (using history API). Read about this in angular $location docs (Hashbang and HTML5 Modes): https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location